# I can´t pivot a data frame

Tags: r

I have this data:

dput(head([data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26KKz.png)))

and I want to generate a dataframe like the text down with the data above:

dput(head([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEGzz.png)))

I tried with many options (pivot tables in excel, using cast and dcast in R studio, making subsets and pasting before...) but I always get nothing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Please don't share entire files - people aren't likely to download files to their system from unknown sources, and this could be a vector for spreading malware. Please share a sample of your data and your desired output directly here (e.g., using `dput(head(data))`

Comment: Sorry, I don´t know how to paste my data properly, I get dissorded text, so I though to give my own entire data.

Comment: Just do `dput(head(your_dataframe))` and paste the results in your question

Comment: In the question posting text box, mark all your `dput` output, and then click in the top bar on the `{ }` symbol (or press ctrl-k). This will format your text so it looks like code. (Alternatively, put four spaces before each line - this does the same thing)

Comment: David, you have to run `dput(head(your_dataframe))` in R and then copy paste the output here

Comment: The link in the first comment for making a reproducible example has instructions on how to add a sample of data we can work with. Read that post so folks don't have to repeat that same information in comments here. It's also helpful to see what you've tried that hasn't worked, and what your approach is.

Answer (score 1):

```
require(tidyr)
gather(data, "to", "weight", 2:9)
```

Or, the same thing with `reshape2`/`data.table`:

```
require(reshape2) # or data.table, if you'd like to use that
melt(data, id.vars="from",variable.name="to",value.name="weight")
```